# Grouping successive dates in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Given a list of datetimes:

```
A= [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 16, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 25, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0),
   ]
```

I want to group datetimes whose difference is 1 day so that the output is :

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 16, 0, 0), 
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 25, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0)]]
```

I have tried this, but it is failing:

```
res = []
temp = []
l = len(A)-1
for i,v in enumerate(A):
    if i+1 > l:
        break

    if abs(v.days() - A[i+1].days()) == 1:
        temp.append(v)
    else:
        if temp:
            temp.append(v)
            res.append(temp)
            temp = []
print(res)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version of the question was about integers, so here is the answer to "grouping integers whose difference is 1" first (see below for datetime objects).

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to group them like this:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

counter = count()
A= [1,14,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
out = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(A, key=lambda v:v-next(counter))]
print(out)
# [[1], [14], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
```

If you really want the isolated values to appear out of any list, just add:

```
out = [sublist[0] if len(sublist)==1 else sublist for sublist in out]
print(out)
[1, 14, [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
```

`next(counter)` will return 0, 1, 2... and so on every time it is called. If the difference between values is 1, `v-next(counter)` will be constant, and groupby groups the items for which this remains constant.

---

For the second version of the question, we can keep the same principle for `datetime` objects with one day difference: we subtract a `datetime.timedelta(days=next(counter))` instead of just `next(counter)`.

```
from itertools import groupby, count
import datetime


A= [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 16, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 25, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0),
   ]

counter = count()  

out = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(A, key=lambda v:v-datetime.timedelta(days=next(counter)))]

# print(out)
# [1], [14], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]


out = [sublist[0] if len(sublist)==1 else sublist for sublist in out]
print(out)

# [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 16, 0, 0), 
#  [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 25, 0, 0),
#   datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0)]]
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry
if the list contains [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 0, 0)] how will I proceed?

Comment: I added an update to the answer. If this was actually your final goal, maybe you can edit your question to include it  - well, I see that you just did :)

Comment: Could also just use indices: `[list(group) for _, group in groupby(enumerate(A), lambda v: v[1]-v[0])]`. Removes need for separate counter variable. Of course, this only applies for your first example using only integers.